# install amavisd-new failed on ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, amavisd-new

This happend when I try to install amavisd-new on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
mandi@rez-latitude:~$ sudo apt-get install -y amavisd-new
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libberkeleydb-perl libconvert-binhex-perl libconvert-tnef-perl
  libconvert-uulib-perl libio-multiplex-perl libmime-tools-perl
  libnet-cidr-perl libnet-server-perl libunix-syslog-perl pax
Suggested packages:
  apt-listchanges arj dspam lhasa libnet-ldap-perl libsnmp-perl libzeromq-perl
  lzop nomarch rpm altermime ripole liblog-log4perl-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amavisd-new libberkeleydb-perl libconvert-binhex-perl libconvert-tnef-perl
  libconvert-uulib-perl libio-multiplex-perl libmime-tools-perl
  libnet-cidr-perl libnet-server-perl libunix-syslog-perl pax
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,380 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,952 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libberkeleydb-perl:amd64.
(Reading database ... 283931 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libberkeleydb-perl_0.62-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libberkeleydb-perl:amd64 (0.62-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libconvert-binhex-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libconvert-binhex-perl_1.125-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libconvert-binhex-perl (1.125-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmime-tools-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libmime-tools-perl_5.509-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmime-tools-perl (5.509-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libconvert-tnef-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libconvert-tnef-perl_0.18-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libconvert-tnef-perl (0.18-1) ...
```

......

```
Selecting previously unselected package libconvert-uulib-perl.
Setting up libnet-server-perl (2.009-2) ...
Setting up amavisd-new (1:2.11.0-6.1ubuntu1) ...
Creating/updating amavis user account...
Job for amavis.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status amavis.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript amavis, action "start" failed.
● amavis.service - LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/amavis; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-10-18 09:50:03 CEST; 6ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 412289 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/amavis start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude amavis[412289]: Starting amavisd:
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude amavis[412301]:   The value of variable $myhostname is "rez- 
latitude", but should have been
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude amavis[412301]:   a fully qualified domain name; perhaps 
uname(3) did not provide such.
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude amavis[412301]:   You must explicitly assign a FQDN of this 
host to variable $myhostname
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude amavis[412301]:   in /etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id, or fix what 
uname(3) provides as a host's
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude amavis[412301]:   network name!
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude amavis[412289]: (failed).
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude systemd[1]: amavis.service: Control process exited, 
code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude systemd[1]: amavis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 18 09:50:03 rez-latitude systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter.
dpkg: error processing package amavisd-new (--configure):
 installed amavisd-new package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amavisd-new
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can somone explain why this happend?